# SML Contains using a String and Charlist

Tags: string, function, contains, sml, string-comparison

I am trying to compare a String to a Charlist in SML, using the REPL I have this:

```
val alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
val charalphabet = explode alphabet;
val str = "the quick brown fox";
val res = Char.contains(str, charalphabet);
```

This throws an error because I am trying to compare a String to a Charlist, and contains only compares a String to a single Char. Does anyone have any ideas how to work around this? I could explode the String str and compare Char lists however I am unsure if their is a function for this. So if anyone has any ideas about functions or things I can read into please let me know, the goal is to see if a String contains a per-defined Charlist.

I am extremely new to SML so any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Is there any reason that `wxyz` is missing from your alphabet? In any event: Hint 1: `List.all` is useful. Hint 2: `Char.contains str` is a function of type `char -> bool`.

Comment: I edited the post, the missing "wxyz" was typo by me. I am going to look into the two things you just mentioned. The function I had earlier today was: fun isPangram c = if Char.contains(c, charalphabet) then true else false; is on the right track even though it is not working?

Comment: Yes, it is on the right track in the sense that `Char.contains` is a natural tool for the job and you are aware of what the problem is with your current code. But note that `Char.contains` is a curried function, so putting parentheses around the inputs like that isn't correct, so you have another problem in addition to the char vs. char list problem.

Comment: I thought putting parenthesis was something that was irrelevant and done for aesthetic purposes, but I guess I was mistaken. So is it possible to define my own contains function that checks if a String contains all the chars in the alphabet and returns true if it does?

Comment: Yes you can define what you want, but there is a 1 line definition which uses List.all and Char.contains.

Comment: I think I am getting ahead of myself, let me look into List.all and try some more, thanks for the help thus far!

Comment: So if I understand this correctly: List.all applies something to all elements in the list, and contains sees if a Char is in a String, so my idea is a function that flows like this: fun isPangram s = List.all Char.contains str charalphabet however, I want to compare a whole bunch of Chars, and Char.contains seems to only compare one Char. also I just tried this in the REPL, and had type issues, however I don't think I'm understanding how this function needs to flow. I understand what I want to do but I'm having trouble converting it in SML. I apologize if this is painful

Comment: Just put parentheses around `Char.contains str` so that `List.all` groups it correctly. `List.all` is designed to apply a Boolean-valued function to all elements in a list (or until it finds a counterexample and returns `false`).

Comment: Last question I promise: so fun isPanram s = List.all(Char.contains str, charalphabet); is what Im looking for? However in the REPL I have type issues and Im not sure if this will check to see if a String that I filter in is a Pangram, or has every element in the alphabet.

Comment: Your right parenthesis is too far to the right and you have an `s` vs. `str` inconsistency. Also, you have a comma that shouldn't be there. You might want to read up on the syntax of curried functions.

Comment: I don't think I quite understand still, I will have to read up on this more because I don't quite understand how to change up this function to do what I need it to. I really appreciate all the help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way that you put parenthesis around and put a comma between the arguments of `Char.contains` suggests that you are having some trouble understanding how functions like `Char.contains` work. Such functions are called curried functions and it is somewhat misleading if you think of them as functions of two variables.

Char.contains is a function of type `string -> char -> bool`. The input type is a string and its output type is a function of type `char -> bool`. More often than not this output function is instantly evaluated:

```
- Char.contains "cat" #"a";
val it = true : bool
```

Which might look like you are evaluating a function of 2 variables, but in reality you are evaluating 2 functions of 1 variable: the function `Char.contains` is evalauted at `"cat"` to return a function of type `char -> bool` and this latter function is evaluated aat `#"a"` to get the final result.

Note that it is possible to use `Char.contains` to return a function which *isn't* immediately evaluated. For example:

```
val isVowel = Char.contains "aeiou";
```

Here `isVowel` is a function which can be used to check if a (lower case) character is a vowel.

`List.all` is a function of type `('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> bool`. To use it to check if all elements if a list of a given type (e.g. `char`) satisfy a property, you need to pass it a function which takes elements of that type and returns a Boolean value (e.g. a function of type `char -> bool`;

But -- we already know how to manufacture functions of type `char -> bool`: use `Char.contains`. For any string `s` , `Char.contains s` is a function which can be passed to `List.all` and then the resulting function applied to the list of characters in the alphabet:

```
val alphabet = explode "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
fun isPanagram s = List.all (Char.contains s) alphabet;
```

The reason that `Char.contains s` is enclosed in parentheses is because function evaluation is left-associative. Without the parentheses, SML would parse it as
`(List.all Char.contains) s`, which makes no sense.

Comment: Thanks so much for the in-depth response/ explanation. With some changes that you recommended I got my function working perfectly. Again thanks for sticking with me and taking the time to explain everything so well!